# Произошла ошибка базового поставщика в Open. ADO EDM

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Никак не могу справиться с ерундовой на первый взгляд ошибкой. Вроде гуглил уже, но многие исправления, которые предлагались на Stackoverflow не подошли. Все еще просто не успел попробовать, т.к. некоторые из них требуют достаточно времени и копания в системе. Я не думаю, что всё так сложно.

В общем-то я создал тестовый проект Windows Forms и пытался подключиться к MS SQL Server Compact 4.0 через ADO.NET EDM. Однако при попытке достать информацию из таблицы получаю вышеописанную ошибку.

Connection string привожу:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyBDEntities"   connectionString="metadata=res://*/testModel.csdl|res://*/testModel.ssdl|res://*/testModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\Users\Work\Documents\MyBD.sdf&quot;"
          providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="TestADOApp2.Properties.Settings.MyBDConnectionString"
          connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyBD.sdf" providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Надеюсь, что, возможно, вы сможете помочь.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Да, поторопился я. Всё решилось.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyBDEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/testModel.csdl|res://*/testModel.ssdl|res://*/testModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=|DataDirectory|\MyBD.sdf;password=******&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Вот такая конфигурация работает нормально. Предлагаю закрыть тему.